# Contenteditable div for previewing a textarea doesn't fire at start

Tags: jquery, textarea, contenteditable

I have a div like this : `<div class='textarea_preview' contenteditable='false'></div>` which show a rendered preview of another textarea when I edit it, this is the code :

```
$('textarea').keyup(function()
{
    var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    $(this).prevAll('.textarea_preview').html(keyed);
});
```

So now I would like to have this preview when the DOM is ready and not only when I edit the textarea.

Any trick to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as -

```
$('.textarea_preview').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).next('textarea').val());
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CvuhF/2/)

Comment: The problem is that I have many textareas in the page so I need to fill the 'textarea_preview' with the first next 'textarea'

Comment: No worries I found it! : var textarea_content = $('.textarea_preview').nextAll('textarea').val();
$('.textarea_preview').html(textarea_content);